# What does minorId and majorId in commitId signify?

Tags: javers

Can someone explain the difference between majorId and minorId in the CommitId object ?
I noticed that all the entries in jv_snapshots contain only majorId (as returned by the changes api).
Would really like to understand if i can leverage minorId somehow for intermittent commits.

Answer (score 0):

`MinorId` is used to maintain `commitId` uniqueness when multiple threads are committing to the same Javers instance :

```
def "should allow concurrent javers commits"() {
        given:
        def threads = 10
        def uuids = (1..10).collect { UUID.randomUUID().hashCode() }

        when:
        withPool(threads) {
            (1..threads).collectParallel {
               javers.commit("author", new SnapshotEntity(id: uuids[it-1]))
               databaseCommit()
            }
        }

        then:
        uuids.forEach {
            assert javers.findSnapshots(QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(it, SnapshotEntity).build()).size() == 1
        }
    }
```

log:

```
15:31:54.305 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.00, snapshots:1, author:author, changes - NewObject:1), done in 55 millis (diff:49, persist:6)
15:31:54.305 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.01, snapshots:1, author:author, changes - NewObject:1), done in 55 millis (diff:49, persist:6)
15:31:54.306 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.03, snapshots:1, author:author, changes - NewObject:1), done in 55 millis (diff:49, persist:6)
15:31:54.306 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.04, snapshots:1, author:author, changes - NewObject:1), done in 56 millis (diff:49, persist:7)
15:31:54.306 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.05, snapshots:1, author:author, changes - NewObject:1), done in 56 millis (diff:49, persist:7)
15:31:54.306 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.09, snapshots:1, author:author, changes - NewObject:1), done in 56 millis (diff:49, persist:7)
15:31:54.307 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.08, snapshots:1, author:author, changes - NewObject:1), done in 57 millis (diff:49, persist:8)
15:31:54.307 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.02, snapshots:1, author:author, changes - NewObject:1), done in 57 millis (diff:49, persist:8)
15:31:54.307 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.06, snapshots:1, author:author, changes - NewObject:1), done in 57 millis (diff:49, persist:8)
15:31:54.307 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.07, snapshots:1, author:author, changes - NewObject:1), done in 57 millis (diff:49, persist:8)
```